# How to create participant , there identities via rest api that generated by composer rest server without importing cards via /importwallets?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have created bna and deployed in composer rest server by enabling passport and multi-user, How to create participant, their identities via rest API that generated by composer rest server without importing cards via import wallets? and there is no proper documentation for this.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you've done a /Wallet/Import of an identity that can issue other identities:

eg. REST Endpoint

```
/Wallets/Import
```

browse for file your exported admin card eg. `netadmin.card` and Import it. use the `POST /wallet/{name}/setDefault` REST method if you need to set this as the default id.

you would then do:

Add a participant (say a participant called trader1):

- eg. say 'Trader'

```
Post /Trader

{
  "$class": "org.acme.trading.Trader",
  "tradeId": "trader1",
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe"
}
```

Issue an identity mapped to that participant above (say jdoe):

Under /System;

```
POST /system/identities/issue:
{
```

"participant": "resource:org.acme.trading.Trader#trader1",
  "userID": "jdoe",
  "options": {}
}

You should get a business network card in your Downloads folder - from your REST server go to /Wallets

```
/POST /wallet/import
```

Import the wallet, giving it the `userId@your-network` parameter when prompted. Then set that as the default user (eg /POST wallet/{name}/setDefault ) if you want to use it in your browser.

Comment: Do I need to login with the user first which has access to issue identities feature?

Comment: set the administrative business network card as default (setDefault) card, ie the one that has ability to issue further identities via REST API,  (which you can enrol and export elsewhere). A programmatic example (using REST APIs) is shown here -> https://medium.com/@CazChurchUk/developing-multi-user-application-using-the-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-b3b88e857ccc