# Ability to use participant identity created with Composer CLI to launch composer rest server

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have created participants using the node CLI and Business Network Connection. I have also assigned them with an identity.

Now; is it possible to use this identity to launch the composer-rest-server as this participant? E.g. could this be turn into a card that I can import and use? I have the userSecret saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see answer here -> [How to create participant , there identities via rest api that generated by composer rest server without importing cards via /importwallets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48838803/how-to-create-participant-there-identities-via-rest-api-that-generated-by-comp)

for more detail.

But yes - you can use that BUSINESS NETWORK card (eg. like: restadmin@my-network) as the 'identity' (because the identity's cert/key are part of the BN card that connects the business network, when you use it to launch your REST server instance).  So that would be an administrative id that's used to launch a REST server.

Then (therafter), any standard blockchain identities could come along and USE the REST API client (eg. after authenticating, etc etc)  - that's why you've stood up the REST server instance :0-)  - each REST client user,  will connect to the REST server with their own BN cards (and again, containing its own identity cert/key, and which is mapped to a participant in the Composer business network) and that user's card would be imported into the users REST API Wallet to then use to interact with the deployed business network as that identity.